# torchvision.io cannot find reference read_image() in __init.py__

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I am trying to import read_image from torchvision.io
and when i hover the error it says

`torchvision.io cannot find reference 'read_image' in '__init.py__'`

```
from torchvision.io import read_image
```

I am following this example

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html

`from torchvision.io import read_image ImportError: cannot import name 'read_image' from 'torchvision.io' (C:\Users\X\.conda\envs\Pytorch37\lib\site-packages\torchvision\io\__init__.py)`
This is the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You need to upgrade the version of your pytorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

```
# Just for my version of system and cuda, you need to replace the cmd below based on your condition
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

Comment: Works without errors @ MacBook Air M1 after upgrade `torch` 1.9.0 -> 1.11.0, `torchvision` 0.10.0 -> 0.12.0.

Comment: If your using Jupyter Notebook, also make sure to restart and check if you're using the correct kernel

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a version not compatible.

Can you print your torchvision version ?

```
import torchvision  
print(torchvision.__version__)
```

I don't know which one you need but you can look for it at least.